# Wrapping text around a pdf

Tags: floats, diagrams

I am making a poster and have an image which is of PDF format. I want the picture to be to right of the block it is in and the text to run down the left hand side of it?

I have searched but can not get anything to work for me

In response to the first comment I have now tried

```
 \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[scale=2]{BOB.pdf}
 \end{minipage}
```

But I get the image in the center of my box rather than to the right hand side.

MWE: `

```
\documentclass[final,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> { \usetheme{Berlin} \usetheme{Dreuw} } 
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym} 
\boldmath 
\usepackage{wrapfig, graphicx, upgreek} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{} 
    \begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{.30\linewidth}
    \begin{block}{Monte Carlo Technique}
           When we have..accuracy through looking at the proportion of points inside and outside the circle. 
    \begin{wrapfigure}[13]{r}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{BOB.pdf} 
    \end{wrapfigure}
    The Monte Carlo ....vvfvfdv 
     \end{block}    
     \end{column}
     \end{columns}
\end{frame}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please may you expand on that please. I have never used latex for a poster and am unsure of what you mean and what is required.

Comment: I am writing up an answer. I think it is a little more complicated, than I thought...

Answer (score 3):

**Caveat Emptor**:

This answer, while largely addressing OP's quest (OP is using `beamer` class) , is buggy on one ground: the line breaks are not proper, as `wrapfig` is used together with columns which is perhaps based on some form of list or trivlist in its implementation; and `wrapfig` and `list`ish stuff are not compatible. (See the last example!)

Work around is to add `~` at places where line break is not desired.

**Code**:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[11]{r}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{demo}
\caption{My Demo} 
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1] 
\end{document}
```

Here's how the code works:

- First about the packages: `lipsum` is for inserting random text for demonstration. I am passing the `demo` option to `graphicx` for getting a dummy figure, once again, for the purposes of illustration.
- Now the functional part:  `\begin{wrapfigure}[11]{r}{0.4\textwidth}`

  - the number `11` is the number of lines to wrap around the figure. This is optional, that is, LaTeX can guess this number.
  - the `r` signifies, place the figure on the right (equivalently, let the lines run down on the left). This is a mandatory argument to the `wrapfigure enviroment`.
  - the next argument is the width of the image. This argument is mandatory too.

**Output**:

[image: lipsum.png]

---

**To the OP**

Here is an equivalent MWE:

```
\documentclass[demo,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {\usetheme{Berlin}} 
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym} 
\boldmath 
\usepackage{wrapfig, graphicx, upgreek, lipsum} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{} 
   \begin{columns}[t]
   \begin{column}{.30\linewidth}
   \begin{block}{Monte Carlo Technique}
      When we have..accuracy through looking at the proportion of points inside and outside the circle. 
   \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{BOB} 
  \end{wrapfigure}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{block}    
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}{}
\end{document}
```

Here's the output I (and a [few](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot) [other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) chat regulars) get:

[image: thanknicola.png]

Comment: \documentclass[final,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
  {
  \usetheme{Berlin}
  \usetheme{Dreuw}
  }
  \usepackage{times}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
  \boldmath
  \usepackage{wrapfig}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{ upgreek }
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}

Comment: \begin{block}{Monte Carlo Technique}

\begin{wrapfigure}[13]{r}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{BOB.pdf}
\caption{My Demo} 
\end{wrapfigure}
The Monte Carlo has some very useful properties especially in higher dimensions. This can be demonstrated fairly simply. It be shown that the Monte Carlo error is random and does not suffer from the 'curse of dimensionalitly'. That is we do not need to increase the number of iterations exponentially to maintain a certain level...the central limit theorem.

Comment: You mean like this or edit the question?

Comment: @KaneBlackburn This would help the potential answerers get more details about your problem. So, could you please post that in the question? (I should have said, I apologise).

Comment: Please do not apologise you are being more than helpful!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8617/discussion-between-kan-and-kane-blackburn)